# NSToolbar customization not available

Tags: objective-c, customization, nstoolbar

ALL,

According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstoolbar/1516962-allowsusercustomization?language=objc) the property is available since macOS 10.4.

I'm on High Sierra 10.13 and getting an error:

```
../src/osx/cocoa/toolbar.mm:465:15: warning: instance method '-allowsUserCustomization:' not found (return type defaults to 'id')
      [-Wobjc-method-access]
        [self allowsUserCustomization:YES];
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../src/osx/cocoa/toolbar.mm:339:12: note: receiver is instance of class declared here
@interface wxNSToolbar : NSToolbar
           ^
../src/osx/cocoa/toolbar.mm:466:15: warning: instance method '-autosaveConfiguration:' not found (return type defaults to 'id')
      [-Wobjc-method-access]
        [self autosaveConfiguration:YES];
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../src/osx/cocoa/toolbar.mm:339:12: note: receiver is instance of class declared here
@interface wxNSToolbar : NSToolbar
           ^
```

Could someone please explain what is going on?

TIA!!

[EDIT]

I made a following implementation:

```
- (NSArray *)toolbarDefaultItemIdentifiers:(NSToolbar*)toolbar
{
    auto array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:&m_default[0] count:m_default.size()];;
    return [NSArray arrayWithObjects:&m_default[0] count:m_default.size()];;
}

- (NSArray *)toolbarAllowedItemIdentifiers:(NSToolbar*)toolbar
{
    auto array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:&m_allowed[0] count:m_allowed.size()];;
    return [NSArray arrayWithObjects:&m_allowed[0] count:m_allowed.size()];;
}
```

However, after executing the line `auto array = ...`, program crashes.

The variables m_allowed and m_default are of the type std::vector.

The vectors do have elements in them. Running under lldb I can see their content.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting a property in Objective-C:

```
self.allowsUserCustomization = YES;
```

Using the setter method:

```
[self setAllowsUserCustomization:YES];
```

Comment: Got it. Can I override this: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstoolbar/1516979-runcustomizationpalette?language=objc, to run my code there?

Comment: Why do you want to override `runCustomizationPalette:?

Comment: Is it possible?

Comment: I don't know, it doesn't make any sense. Usually `allowsUserCustomization` is set when the toolbar is created.

Comment: I changed those 2 and now it compiles. But when I run it the customization panel is empty. I looked thru the delegate methods and I don't see anything related to customization. I use png/xpm/svg images in the toolbar. Could you provide some simple code to make the customization panel work? TIA!!

Comment: Post how you create the toolbar in the question please.

Comment: I think I get it. All I need to do is override the NSToolbar delegate' function `toolbarAllowedItemIdentifiers`, whee I will get a toolbar pointer, call its `items()` method and then in the loop add each item identifier into the array that will be returned. Now the question is - how do I ge the toolbar from the delegate?

Comment: one more related question - it gives me error like this: `error: use of undeclared identifier 'getIdentifier'`. How do I fix it? I should be able to use getIdentifier() call right?

Comment: No, I don't think you got it. See [Toolbar Programming Topics for Cocoa](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Toolbars/Toolbars.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000109i).

Comment: I read all articles from the link, but still have a question. There is an available and default toolbar items. My understanding is that available items are the ones that currently displayed in the toolbar and the defaut are the ones that are currently displayed + the ones that could potentialy be displayed in the toolbar. Am I right? If not - how the Kit differ between currently displayed and potentially displayed?

Comment: There is allowed and default items. The allowed items "Include all of your toolbar’s items" and the default items "when user settings don’t contain any custom configuration data for the toolbar". The currently displayed items are in the  `items` property of the toolbar. Initially, at default, before the user customizes the toolbar, `items` is the default items. The default items are also present in the customization palette as default set.

Comment: so if I want to initially display item 1,3 and 4 and items 3, 5 and 6 to be allowed but not initially displayed - what do I do? No custom configuration here.

Comment: I just re-read you last comment and I think I got it. The default array will be a displayed items and allowed array will have displayed and potentially displayed.

Comment: Tes, that's right.

Comment: one hopefully last question. Please see the edit to the OP. Thx.

Comment: This is an unrelated question about `NSArray`, post a new question please.

Comment: done. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76359216/convert-stdvector-to-nsarray. Thx.